# SQL Join Sorting and Limiting Results

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the following two tables (populated with more data):

**rating**

```
ID | user_id | rating_value | date
1    1         0.6            2016-04-02
2    2         0.75           2016-04-05
3    1         0.4            2016-04-08
4    2         0.5            2016-04-12
```

**recommendation**

```
ID | user_id | recommendation_text | date
1    1         'a'                   2016-04-03
2    2         'b'                   2016-04-07
3    1         'c'                   2016-04-09
```

I would like to select the recommendation_text, user_id, and latest rating value from the rating table for each row in the recommendation table.

I am having trouble only returning the latest rating value:

```
SELECT rec.user_id, rec.recommendation_text, rec.recommendation.date, rating.rating_value, rating.date
FROM recommendation AS rec
JOIN rating
ON rec.user_id = rating.user_id;
```

Returns (as expected) all values joined to the recommendations. The end result I'd like to produce is:

```
user_id | recommendation_text | recommendation_date | rating_value | rating_date
1         'a'                   2016-04-03            0.6            2016-04-02
2         'b'                   2016-04-07            0.75           2016-04-05
1         'c'                   2016-04-09            0.4            2016-04-08
```

Comment: I think there is a piece of information missing here, I'm not sure how you pick which rating to attach to which recommendation. In your example query you only join on user id, but if that was the only key you cared about there wouldn't be more than one recommendation per user.  Is ID a foreign key from one table to the other?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: you can use Top command for limiting result a after select like select top 3 ...  and "order by rating_date" and the end of command for sort

Comment: @Kateract the rating to attach is the last rating that exists that has a date that is prior to the recommendation_date. So in this case, I want the 'c' text from recommendation to only be linked to 0.4, not both 0.4 and 0.6. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below query which will work in **PostgreSQL**, mySQL and SQL server

```
SELECT rec.user_id, rec.recommendation_text, rec.date, rating.rating_value, rating.date
FROM  recommendation AS rec
JOIN rating ON rec.user_id = rating.user_id 
JOIN 
(SELECT rec.id as id1, max(rating.id) as id2
FROM recommendation AS rec
JOIN rating
ON rec.user_id = rating.user_id AND rec.date >rating.date
GROUP BY rec.id ) t
on t.id1= rec.id and t.id2=rating.id;
```

**[Demo link here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/157e4/1)**

**update based on comment:**

> FYI, that query will only work if the id's in your rating table are in the same order as the dates in the rating table. If you end up with a record with a higher ID but an earlier date, then it will return the higher ID instead of the later date

```
 SELECT rec.user_id, rec.recommendation_text, rec.date, rating.rating_value, rating.date
    FROM  recommendation AS rec
    JOIN rating ON rec.user_id = rating.user_id 
    JOIN 
    (SELECT rec.id as id1, max(rating.date) as id2
    FROM recommendation AS rec
    JOIN rating
    ON rec.user_id = rating.user_id AND rec.date >rating.date
    GROUP BY rec.id ) t
    on t.id1= rec.id and t.id2=rating.date;
```

**[updated Demo link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/157e4/4)**

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks! I'm still a little bit confused on what the bottom half is actually doing, but I'll work on debugging that on my own.

Comment: Explanation: The part above produces multiple results for a JOIN, bottom part contains the date check and then for each recommendation finds the corresponding last rating's id (using `max(rating.id) group by rec.id`) which is then used as JOIN to find the exact recommendation text.

Comment: @DerekA. FYI, that query will only work if the id's in your rating table are in the same order as the dates in the rating table.  If you end up with a record with a higher ID but an earlier date, then it will return the higher ID instead of the later date.

Comment: @Kateract I strongly suspect that ids in rating are in same order as the dates, i.e. the latest one get greater id(auto-incremented). However, i've still updated my answer based on your comment!

Comment: Thank you both. To make sure I'm understanding correctly @Kateract, this is because the JOIN on rating is assuming the max(rating.id) will be the most recent? That is the case here, so the results will work, but is there also a way to enforce the sorting?

Comment: @DerekA. Yes, and I believe the updated answer provides a solution to this, but I have posted an alternative answer that also accomplishes this without a subselect, which may perform better depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT rec.user_id, rec.recommendation_text, rec.recommendation.date, rating.rating_value, rating.date
FROM recommendation AS rec
JOIN rating
ON rec.user_id = rating.user_id
where recommendation.date = 
(Select top 1 rec_order.date from recommendation AS rec_order where recorder.user_id=rating.user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method without subselect:

```
select rec.user_id, rec.recommendation_text, rec.dates, rat.rating_value, rat.dates
from recommendation as rec
left join rating as rat on rat.user_id = rec.user_id and rat.dates < rec.dates
left join rating as rat1
on rat.user_id = rat1.user_id and rat.dates < rat1.dates and rat1.dates < rec.dates
where rat1.id is null
```